# Python new-style-class-related question

Tags: python, new-style-class

I am a python learner and currently hacking up a class with variable number of fields as in the ["Bunch of Named Stuff" example here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/).

```
class Bunch:
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)
```

I also want to write a `__setattr__` in this class in order to check the input attribute name. But, the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/attribute-access.html) says,

> If __setattr__() wants to assign to an
>   instance attribute, it should not
>   simply execute "self.name = value" --
>   this would cause a recursive call to
>   itself. Instead, it should insert the
>   value in the dictionary of instance
>   attributes, e.g., "self.__dict__[name]
>   = value".
>   For new-style classes, rather than
>   accessing the instance dictionary, it
>   should call the base class method with
>   the same name, for example,
>   "object.__setattr__(self, name,
>   value)".

In that case, should I also use `object.__dict__` in the `__init__` function to replace `self.__dict__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should define your class as `class Bunch(object)`, but continue to refer to `self.__dict__`.

You only need to use the `object.__setattr__` method while you are defining  the `self.__setattr__` method to prevent infinite recursion. `__dict__` is not a method, but is an attribute on the object itself, so `object.__dict__` would not work.

Comment: The part about `object.__dict__` is more or less clear. However, the reason for using `baseclass.__setattr__` seems to be to call the custom overload in the base class. Am I right?

Comment: I wouldn't say that you call the custom one in the base class. Since you're redefining how the "custom overload" method updates attributes, you can't use that method inside of itself. Since you're trying to update an attribute without going through your new custom mechanism, you refer to it from the base class instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
class Bunch:
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        #do your verification stuff
        self.__dict__[name] = value
```

or with new-style class :

```
class Bunch(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        #do your verification stuff
        super(Bunch, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```